# reply on the same interface in windows server

Tags: windows, routing

we have two servers each with 2 NIC, and three services (daemons) installed on each server, the first service use the first NIC and require load balancer, the two other services not requiring the use of the load balancer and use the second NIC

the problem, is which gateway to configure ?
if the gw1, all services will pass through the load balancer and it causes problems for 2 services

if the gw2, the first service wont work, the 2 others will

if the gw1 and gw2, then it's hazardous

now, in Linux/Unix it's easy, the "reply on the same interface" resolve such problem, i am looking a way to do it in the windows servers

is it possible ?

thanks

Comment: There are way too many unknowns in this question. Most importantly what mode is the load balancer operating in? If the load balancer is operating in proxy or DSR mode the answer is going to be simple, but it's not the same answer in both cases. You also need to specify the network configuration of the networks the two interfaces are connected to.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few possible solutions to play with:

1. **IP Application Binding**: some apps, like DNS and IIS allows you to select the IP address that the application can use to reply from. For the apps that doesn't have such option, you can use a 3rd party tool to force the binding (never tried any myself, and this is directly from Google): https://github.com/katlogic/bindip
2. **NIC Bind Order**: if you have both NICs in the same subnet, you can try to set the order of which Windows uses them to communicate. I usually configure the NIC with the GW to be at the bottom list to force connections to my local services first. For **2008/2012**: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732472(v=ws.10).aspx for **2016**: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/network-subsystem/net-sub-interface-metric